# Session keeps resetting on Node.js Express

Tags: node.js, session

I have a basic post request:

```
router.post('/page',multipart(), function (req,res) {
    if(req.session.book=="") {
        console.log("Creating new session")
        req.session.book="Hello!"
    }
```

Which checks to see if there is a string in a session variable called 'book' and if the string is empty, a string is added to it.

My hopes is to get a new session variable when I post to this route only once.
But for some reason, on every request I make, I get a console message saying "Creating new session" 
Why does the session variable keeps resetting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

once you add something to the session, you need to save it again to the sessionStore.  That is generally done with `req.session.save()`

There are certain times when the session is automatically saved.  When `res.end` is called, for example.  But as you have experienced, that doesn't always happen, so I find it a good practice to save manually.

Comment: That did it! I need to wait 9 minutes (stackoverflow limitations) before I can mark your answer as the correct answer. But I'll make sure I do that later. Thanks a lot!